# How to persist cookies from WebViewClient to URLConnection, browser, or other file download technique in android

Tags: java, android, asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication

We have a .net forms auth enabled site that the user visits via a WebViewClient in our android app.  One of the features of the site is the ability to login and download some PDF files, however you need to be logged in to download the PDFs.

We are currently implementing `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and are downloading the pdf via the following code when the correct condition is met.

```
URL u = new URL(url);
URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
stream.readFully(buffer);
stream.close();

DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/download/file.pdf"));
fos.write(buffer);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

From the IIS logs, its apparent that IIS does not consider this request to be logged in and redirects it to the login page.

What we need is a way to download the file with the auth cookie persisted in the file download request but we are at a loss as to how to persist the cookie.

Another viable solution for us is to persist the auth cookie between the WebViewClient and the android browser.  If we could do that, we'd just open the PDF file via the default action in the browser.

Edit: It looks like I can set the auth cookie manually via

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "");
```

Now I just need to figure out how to read the auth cookie out of the WebViewClient

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're using [ASP.NET Forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx), you'll need to copy the [forms auth cookie](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443) from the [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to the [`URLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html).  Luckily this is pretty straight forward.  This code lives in an implementation of [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
string url = "http://site/generatePdfBehindFormsAuth";

// get an instance of a cookie manager since it has access to our auth cookie
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

// get the cookie string for the site.  This looks something like ".ASPXAUTH=data"
String auth = cookieManager.getCookie(url).toString();

URLConnection conn = (URLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();

// Set the cookie string to be sent for download.  In our case we're just copying the
//   entire cookie string from the previous connection, so all values stored in 
//   cookies are persisted to this new connection.  This includes the aspx auth 
//   cookie, otherwise it would not be authenticated
//   when downloading the file.  
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", auth);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.connect();

// get the filename from the servers response, its typical value is something like:
//   attachment; filename="GeneratedPDFFilename.pdf"
String filename = conn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition").split("\"")[1];

// by default, we'll store the pdf in the external storage directory
String fileRoot = "/sdcard/";

// Complete the download
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileRoot, filename));
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len1 = 0;
while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 
{
    f.write(buffer,0, len1);
}
f.close();
in.close();
```

**NOTE:** One thing to be aware of is that you should **NOT** make a call to [`getContentLength`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29) on your [`URLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html).  After 4 hours of debugging, wireshark finally showed that, if you call [`getContentLength`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29), the cookie would be sent for the request that gets the content length, but **the cookie will not be sent for subsequent requests, even on the same instance of URLConnection**.  Maybe I am naive and this is by design (the documentation does not indicate that it is by design), but I was unable to manually set the cookie for the subsequent file request by calling [`setRequestProperty`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) after calling [`getContentLength`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29).  If I attempted to do that, I'd get a force close.

Comment: Very useful code, but where is this code setting the cookies? Is is possible to set cookies when browsing to urls using URLConnect?

Comment: Its setting the cookie on this line `conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", auth);`, I'll edit the post to illustrate that more clearly. You have 100% control over the cookie string, both getting it from the `WebView` and setting it in the `URLConnection`, so you can persist any values you want. I reccomend using fiddler or something to observe the cookie string sent by the `WebView`, that way you know what to persist in the `URLConnection`.  In the above case, I just persisted ALL of the cookies.  I could have selectively persisted some and not others, but I opted for the easier option.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the CookieSyncManager class?  I believe this is what is needed to persist cookies received from the server and re-use them.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html

Comment: Yeah I've seen that but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it to do what I need to do. I will look into it more though!  Thanks!

Comment: That seems to be a class to transfer cookies from RAM to storage, not webkit to code, unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: @user778234 you are right, see the documentation on the class: The CookieSyncManager is used to synchronize the browser cookie store between RAM and permanent storage. To get the best performance, browser cookies are saved in RAM. A separate thread saves the cookies between, driven by a timer.